# Wrapper catching exceptions accured on db.run call

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

In our project we always injecting `dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider` in our bean objects and then doing database operations with `db.run(some query)`, it returns Future. How can I write a logging wrapper for `db.run` which will print all sql exceptions.

**Example:**

```
class SomeBeanImpl @Inject()(dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) {
  private val logger = Logger(getClass)

  def someDBQuery() = {
    db.run(some wrong sql query) // exception raised in future, I need to print it with logger
  }
}
```

**Note:**
If I add `.onFailure` on each `db.run` call it will mess up my code very badly. That's why I need write this wrapper for all of `db.run` calls.

If I wrap `db.run` in some function with different signature, I must change it in many places, which is not the best option. How can I do it implicitly?

Comment: What is the problem you are having writing this wrapper?

Comment: @Dima I have no idea how to do it at all.

Comment: `def wrapper(query: String) = db.run(query).onFailure { case ex => logger.error(ex) }`

Comment: @Dima if I do so, I need to change db.run to wrapper it in 1000+ places. How can I avoid it, did you read the note section?

Comment: @Dima Can I do it implicitly ?

Comment: Yes, I did read the note section. I am not suggesting that you add .onFailure on each call. Did you read my comment? ;)

Comment: How about extending whatever class `db` is and overriding `run`?

Comment: @Dima You are right, I updated note section. It extends `DatabaseComponent` trait which is tricky to extend, so I asking for help.

Comment: Why is tricky to extend? Don't extend it, if it is tricky, just replace it with a wrapper that has a `.run` method with the same parameters. You can also make it implicitly convertible back to `DatabaseComponent` if you have to, although I would not recommend that.

Comment: @Dima `run` is `final`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly create a new wrapper class, you can use the [Pimp My Library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) pattern to create an implicit method which wraps the invocation of `db.run` and attaches a `onFailure` to the `Future`:

```
object MyExtensions {
  class DbExtensions(db: Db) {
    def runAndLog(query: String): Future[String] = {
      val result = db.run(query)
      result.onFailure {
        case e => Logger.getLogger("x").error(s"Exception: $e")
      }
      result
    }
  }
  implicit def dbExtention(db: Db): DbExtensions = new DbExtensions(db)
}

class Db {
  def run(query: String): Future[String] = Future.successful("Hello")
}

object App extends Application {
  import MyExtensions._
  val db = new Db
  db.runAndLog("hello")
}
```

For Scala 2.10 and above, this can be shortened significantly using [Implicit Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html):

```
implicit class DbExtensions(val db: Db) {
  def runAndLog(query: String): Future[String] = {
    val result = db.run(query)
    result.onFailure {
      case e => Logger.getLogger("x").error(s"Exception: $e")
    }
    result
  }
}

class Db {
  def run(query: String): Future[String] = Future.successful("Hello")
}

object App extends Application {
  val db = new Db
  db.runAndLog("hello")
}
```

You can further make `DbExtensions` extend `AnyVal` for a performance optimization:

```
implicit class DbExtensions(val db: Db) extends AnyVal
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a new class:

```
  case class DBWrapper(db: DatabaseComponent) {
     def run(query: String) = db.run(query).onFailure { case e => logger.error(e) } 
  }
```

And replace your `db` wherever you initialize it  with `DBWrapper(db)`. 
You can make the conversions back and forth implicit too, although I would not recommend it in this case.